# Android beta testing service

Tags: android, beta-testing

I've developed android app and want to start some beta testing with as many users as possible. Are there web services to find mobile beta testers, preferrably volunteers?

Comment: For all voters - go check SO rules. 
"...practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession"  is not off topic.

Comment: I agree. I'd like answer for this too! Seems in the scope of SO.

Comment: @user48956 Some people here think they are gods hiding behind their monitors, and close many interesting questions which don't even violate SO rules

Answer (score 2):

Release as a free App in Google Play with 'BETA' attached to the title.

You will get Google based error reports, so you can fix errors, then release a patched version.

Repeat this cycle until you are happy and feel the project is stable, then take 'BETA' away from the title.

Comment: the idea is to collect peoples' opinions about usability, not just QA. But thanks for the answer

Comment: one problem with that is if you release an app as free, you are not allowed to charge for it at a later date. well thats my understanding of it anyway, i may be wrong. also you may not want the negative feedback and reviews that were associated with it in the beta stageas attached to the final product.

Comment: You can not release the _same_ app as _free_ then charge for it later, but you are allow to release a new app and charge for it. Simply upload the non-beta version with a new name (eg, drop the 'beta' from the name) and Google will be happy with that.